# NO CPU interactions in initiating DMA and RDMA operations

Tags: fpga, dma, pci-e, rdma

I'm trying to build/use a PCIe device using DMA/RDMA, and there're some questions:

(1) is it possible to initiate a DMA operation from the device side without interactions with the CPU driver

- I know in most cases, the CPU driver programs the DMA controller to initiate an operation
- But, if the device has the target address and a master DMA controller, is it possible to initiate an operation without any interaction without the driver? (e.g., programs the controller directly from the device codes)
- If it's possible, are there any resources about implementation with Xilinx FPGAs?

(2) Similar to (1), is there no interaction with the CPU driver when using RDMA data transfer (one-sided)?

- I know that the memory registration is done with the driver for memory pinning
- But I wonder that after that process, there're no interactions like RDMA-controller programming by the RDMA driver. If it's true, how does NIC transfer data directly without the driver's programming?
- I know that the target address of memory is stored in a Queue Pair under the name of WQE.

Comment: In (1), how would the device know what address to use for DMA if it doesn’t get it from the driver?

Comment: At the very least, the OS needs to set BME (bus master enable).

Comment: Thanks for your comment.


The situation that I assume is that the driver "initially" sets up the device appropriately (e.g., BME, as you've mentioned) and the required information  is already delivered to the device; for example, target address and length